# List comprehension and 'all' key word

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
nums = ['90']
print(all([((ele == ele[::-1] and int(ele) > 0) for ele in nums)]))
```

my expectation from above code to print `False`, but it is printing `True`. Could you please explain the reason for printing so?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be `False`?

Comment: @Ava: `'90'` does not equal `'09'`

Comment: `all` isn't a keyword, it's the name of a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`((ele == ele[::-1] and int(ele) > 0) for ele in nums)` is your generator, but then you're wrapping that in a list `[((ele == ele[::-1] and int(ele) > 0) for ele in nums)]`. Therefore what you are passing into `all` is:

```
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x059BE070>]
```

In this case all will return `true`.

What you want is:

```
print(all(((ele == ele[::-1] and int(ele) > 0) for ele in nums)))
```

or

```
print(all([(ele == ele[::-1] and int(ele) > 0) for ele in nums]))
```